# I'm struggling to get a Core Data list to sort from a button press

Tags: swift, sorting, swiftui, core-data

Right now I'm trying to get a Core Data list in SwiftUI to be sortable. I've followed along with a Ray Wenderlich tutorial, and did well with it. I then tried to incorporate what I learned there into my own project.  Currently, everything builds and runs with my project. The list to select sorting from appears, and its list of options appear when that button is clicked. However, clicking a new sort does nothing.

I am under the impression from using the tutorial, that I'd need to swap the Core Data object in lieu of the ListSortAccount struct/object. As well, I recognize that this would be easier to do using the ToolBarItemGroup, however there are parts of my projects design that need this sort to be away from the title bar.

I'll put my minimum code below. Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

**This creates the array that the user can pick from after the button press:**

```
struct ListSorterAccount: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var descriptors: [SortDescriptor<AccountCoreData>]
}

extension ListSorterAccount {    
    static let sorts: [ListSorterAccount] = [
        ListSorterAccount(
            id: 0,
            name: "Account A-Z",
            descriptors: [
                SortDescriptor(\AccountCoreData.accountName, order: .forward),
                SortDescriptor(\AccountCoreData.accountDateAdded, order: .forward)]),        
        ListSorterAccount(
            id: 1,
            name: "Account Z-A",
            descriptors: [
                SortDescriptor(\AccountCoreData.accountName, order: .reverse),
                SortDescriptor(\AccountCoreData.accountDateAdded, order: .reverse)])]    
    static var `default`: ListSorterAccount {
        sorts[0]
    }
    
}
```

**This is the view for the button:**

```
struct ListSorterButton: View {    
    @Binding var selectedSort: ListSorterAccount
    let sorts: [ListSorterAccount]
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Picker("Sort By", selection: $selectedSort) {
                ForEach(sorts, id:\.self) { sort in
                    Text(sort.name)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Label("", systemImage: "line.horizontal.3.decrease.circle")
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the view that holds that button (irrelevant code removed for clarity):**

```
struct SearchBarView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: AccountCoreData.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var accounts: FetchedResults<AccountCoreData>
    @State private var selectedSort = ListSorterAccount.default
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ListSorterButton(
                selectedSort: $selectedSort,
                sorts: ListSorterAccount.sorts)
            .onChange(of: selectedSort) { _ in
                accounts.sortDescriptors = selectedSort.descriptors
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And this is the View that contains my list I'm trying to sort  (irrelevant code removed for clarity):**

```
struct AccountList: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: ListSorterAccount.default.descriptors, animation: .default) var accountFetch: FetchedResults<AccountCoreData>

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(accountFetch.filter {
                    self.searchClass.searchText.isEmpty
                    ? true  :
                    $0.wrappedAccountName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchClass.searchText) ||
                    $0.wrappedAccountCity.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.searchClass.searchText)

                }){ account in
                    NavigationLink(value: Route.mainAccountView(account), label: {
                        AccountListCell(accountCoreData: account)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: For the `Picker` to "work" you should provide a `tag` that is
 of the same type as the `selectedSort`. So try this: `Text(sort.name).tag(sort)`.

Comment: I just tried that out, and there was no change to the app.

Comment: Otherwise the picker actually *does* work.

Comment: But you have two different fetch requests, sorting one will not change the order of the other.

Comment: I don’t know how AccountList and SearchBarView relates to each other but you need to remove the fetch request and change the select property to @Binding in the latter